# How to config Remote BLOB Storage(RBS) with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

We have working site for Dynamics crm 4.0 and in it we are storing image into the database. Now  database is growing very fast and server is dying.. now I want to enable the Remote BLOB Storage with Dynamics CRM 4.0. for that I tried to install RBS for testing but everywhere is configure with Sharepoint 2010 not with Dynamics CRM.

Does anybody know how to install and configure with Dynamics CRM 4.0? Does RBS with Standard Edition of SQL Server 2008?

I followed following path to install but it with Sharepoint?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Any modification to the CRM database are not supported, and enabling RBS on the CRM database is a modification to the database schema.

Maybe that is why you did not found any information on how to enable it on the CRM database. Just to be sure, I would log a support request using Partner/Customer source to be sure that this SQL Server feature is not supported. They will tell you if it's supported, and if so, how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

The reason however, is not a technical one

> Modifications to the physical schema of the database, other than adding or updating indexes. This includes any actions performed against the database without going through System Customization. Modifying tables, stored procedures, or views in the database is not supported. Adding tables, stored procedures, or views to the database is also not supported because of referential integrity or upgrade issues. Note   This applies to all Microsoft Dynamics CRM databases and the Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Microsoft Office Outlook local database.

See the description of [Unsupported Customizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928224.aspx)

I assume that you are storing the images in annotations. If the database growth is really a problem, I would recommend to store the images in an other location and reference it.